# Resource controller name inside a route group in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a route like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'],function(){
    Route::resource('users','UserController'); // <-- what is the name of this route
});
```

How can I address the `users` route by its name e.g `route('users')`?
I tested `users` and `admin.users` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 8):

When you register a resourceful route to the controller `Route::resource(...)`, this simple declaration creates multiple routes to handle a variety of actions ([list of all actions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)).

So inside `admin` route group you will have such names for routes:

- `admin.users.index` for GET `admin/users`
- `admin.users.store` for POST `admin/users`
- `admin.users.show` for GET `admin/users/{id}`
- etc ...

Basically, you can list all route names using `php artisan route:list`

Comment: this is a good answer, i wonder why op did not mark this as an answer.

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't work for me in laravel 5.4 :/ the resource under prefix doesn't get the prefix in the route name

Comment: @Srneczek, In laravel 5.4 you should explicitly name your group (if you want). 
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36838375/2353034) should help you to figure out details.

Comment: the op wants to access the route via its name `route('users')`, not by the url. I am having the same problem

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
Route::group(['as'=>'admin.'  ,'prefix'=>'admin'],function(){
    Route::resource('users','UserController'); 
});
```

the name of route will be

```
admin.users.index
admin.users.create
admin.users.store
admin.users.edit
admin.users.update
admin.users.destroy
admin.users.show
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `admin/users`.

The url of the controllers in group will be group prefix then controller resource name. `prefix/resource`

Comment: Thanks , but I want route name not url

Answer (score 0):

By using `php artisan route:list` command print all the routs to the terminal and see its names. it will show `users.index`, `users.create`, `users.update` and so on. 
usage:

```
route('users.index');
//output: example.com/admin/users
```