# Laravel 5.2 - Get route group name in middleware request

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing a middleware in order to handle redirect for guests to protected areas. I have 2 login pages, one for frontend and another one for backend and want the guests redirected to each login page depending on where they enter. I mean:

- If the guest enters a route like `/admin/dashboard` they must be redirected to `/admin/login`.
- If the guest enters route `/messages` they must be redirected to `/login`.

This is my routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('inicio');
});

Route::group(['as'=>'clientRoutes', 'middleware'=>'loginSelector'], function(){
    Route::get('/polizas', function () {
        return view('cliente.polizas');
    });
});

Route::group(['as'=>'adminRoutes','prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>'loginSelector'], function(){
    Route::get('/inicio', function () {
        return view('admin.inicio');
    });
    Route::get('/lista', function () {
        return view('admin.lista');
    });
});
Route::get('/admin/login', function () {
    return view('admin.login');
});
```

In the middleware I was trying to get group name of the route, but cant find the way to get i, something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CustomAuthRedirectMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $grupoRoute = $request->route()->getGroup();
        if($grupoRoute == "adminRoutes"){
            return redirect('/admin/login');
        }else{
            return redirect('/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

If is possible how can I take the group name for doing the redirection? Or if it is impossible how can achieve this redirect?

Comment: You might give this a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838177/how-to-define-route-group-name-in-laravel

Comment: @Samsquanch thanks a lot. Post it as an answer in order to mark as correct and upvote you please. Thats what I am looking for...

Comment: You can go ahead and post exactly how you solved it as an answer since I can only guess. I think that would be a better solution. Just reference that link in your post as well.

Comment: Perfect, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it thanks to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838177/how-to-define-route-group-name-in-laravel) provided by @Samsquanch.

This is the middleware code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $routeName = $request->route()->getName();
    if(strpos($routeName, 'adminRoutes.') === 0){
        if(!Auth::user()){
            return redirect('/admin/login');
        }
    }elseif(strpos($routeName, 'clientRoutes.') === 0){
        if(!Auth::user()){
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Those are my routes:

```
Route::group(['as'=>'clientRoutes.', 'middleware'=>'loginSelector'], function(){
    Route::get('/polizas', function () {
        return view('cliente.polizas');
    });
});

Route::group(['as'=>'adminRoutes.','prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>'loginSelector'], function(){
    Route::get('/inicio', function () {
        return view('admin.inicio');
    });
    Route::get('/lista', function () {
        return view('admin.lista');
    });
});
Route::get('/admin/login', function () {
    return view('admin.login');
});
```

When I go to url `/admin/lista` I get redirected to `/admin/login`, and when I got to `/polizas` I got redirected to `/login`.

If you use my solution you will have to take care what happens in each login form depending on authenticated user role.