# how to prefix the route group and how to call sub route in blade view

Tags: php, laravel

How i create Routes Groups

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Admin','prefix'=>'admin-panel','as'=>'admin'],function(){
    Route::get('/',[
        'as'=>'dashboard',
        'uses'=>'dashboardController@index',
    ]);
});
```

in the blade view i call the route like that

```
{{ url('/') }}
```

i also tried this

```
{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}
```

but i'm getting error like this 
**Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.**

Comment: Have you checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838177/how-to-define-route-group-name-in-laravel

Comment: @Faizan Fayaz i checked but it can't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Admin','prefix'=>'admin-panel','as'=>'admin.'],function(){
    Route::get('/',[
        'as'=>'dashboard',
        'uses'=>'dashboardController@index',
    ]);
});
```

You are missing `.` after the `'as'=>'admin.'`

Then you  can simply use `{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}`

Comment: what i was missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this easy method:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin-panel'],function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'dashboardController@index');
    ................... //specify all your routes here
    ...................
}
```

And you can use

```
url('admin-panel/index')
```

Hope it works.